# How to make a horizontal line?

Tags: css, line

Hi so here's what I want to do,

http://i1377.photobucket.com/albums/ah45/nikilean/line_zpswvrndxwg.jpg

a horizontal line behind the images? There are 8 circles and I want them to be connected with a line

I made it in bootstrap so the lines are divided into two col 6 and inside each col there are 3 col-3

```
 .stepnumber {
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #f9b315;
  vertical-align: middle;
  color: #fff;
  padding-top: 2px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-top: 150px;
  left: -10px;

}

.step {
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #fff;
  margin-top: 80px;
  margin-right:-60px;
  position: absolute;

}





<div class="container">
          <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                      <div class="lineline"><div class=stepnumber>1</div></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                     <div class="step">
                        <div class="workstitle">
                          BOOK
                        </div>

                </div>           
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                      <div class=stepnumber>2</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                      <div class="step">
                        <div class="workstitle">
                          WAIT
                        </div>

                      </div>          
                    </div>
                 </div>
              </div> 

    <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-3">
                  <div class=stepnumber>3 </div> 
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3">
                  <div class="step">
                   <div class="workstitle">
                     FOUND
                   </div> 

            </div>          
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3">
                  <div class=stepnumber>4</div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3">
                  <div class="step">
                   <div class="workstitle">
                     FLY!
                   </div> 

            </div>          
                </div>
          </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please provide CSS.  I can fix it if I know what I am looking at.

Comment: I hate to be pain, but take a look at this fiddle I made for you and get it the way it's supposed to look please.  I am only seeing 1 circle.

http://jsfiddle.net/plushyObject/wb5fLnxw/

Comment: Is there anything I can do for you? I really have no idea why there's only 1 circle

Comment: You've got a couple of answers to choose from.  Good luck!  Hynes's answer looks good too--just a warning when these collapse down on mobile because of bootstrap, you're going to lose the timeline.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the look you're going for by using the `:after` (or `:before`) pseudo class on your wrapping element. You can create a border on the `:after` element and position it behind your circles using z-index.

Below is an example of how you could construct it.

```css
.timeline {
  height: 150px;
  line-height: 150px;
  display: table;
  position: relative;
}
.timeline:after {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0.5em;
  right: 0.5em;
  top: 50%;
  content: "";
  border-top: 3px solid #F9B315;
  z-index: 900;
}
.-item {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  z-index: 1000;
  position: relative;
}
.-item > div {
  margin-left: 0.5em;
  margin-right: 0.5em;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 150px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 18px;
  background-color: #f9b315;
  color: #FFF;
}
.-item:first-of-type > div { margin-left: 0; }
.-item:last-of-type > div { margin-right: 0; }
.-item._number > div {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  line-height: 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="timeline">
  <div class="-item _number">
    <div>1</div>
  </div>
  <div class="-item _title">
    <div>BOOK</div>
  </div>
  <div class="-item _number">
    <div>2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="-item _title">
    <div>WAIT</div>
  </div>
  <div class="-item _number">
    <div>3</div>
  </div>
  <div class="-item _title">
    <div>FOUND</div>
  </div>
  <div class="-item _number">
    <div>4</div>
  </div>
  <div class="-item _title">
    <div>FLY!</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is going to take a little bit of work on your part, but here is a way to put a horizontal line behind the div.

[Here is the fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/plushyObject/wb5fLnxw/)  The trick for the line is to make a div that's only 1px high.  It will take a little bit of thinking on your part:

```
.line{
  height: 1px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: black;
  z-index: 1;
  position: absolute;
  top: 25px;
}
```